Probability of flipping a coin twice getting a head and a tail, independent or dependent?
If I were to flip a coin twice then sample space is {HH,TT,TH,HT}.
Looking at this its clearly that that probability of getting a head and a tial is $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$.
Ok so this is right. But now this is the part that confuses me: Flipping a coin is an independent event so the formula $$P(A \ \textrm{and} \ B) = P(A)\times P(B)$$ should apply.
P(Tails and Heads) = $\frac{1}{2}$ as above, P(getting a Tail) = $\frac{3}{4}$ = P(getting a Head). But P(Tails)$\times$P(Heads) = $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{3}{4} = \frac{9}{16} \neq \frac{1}{2}$. This suggests that it is dependent, which is a contradiction to the coin tosses being independent.
Why is this so?

Wha-at?! The event that has a probability of $3/4$ is getting at least one tail in two tosses. How is that independent of getting at least one head in two tosses? They're the same two tosses!

The independent events are "getting ... on the first toss" and "getting ... on the second toss".  Your "Tails", i.e. getting at least one Tails in two tosses, and "Heads", i.e. getting at least one Heads in two tosses, are certainly not independent.  For example, if you don't get "Tails" you certainly do get "Heads".

When you calculate the product $Pr(H)\times Pr(T)$ you are finding $Pr(H \ \textrm{then}\ T)$.
This is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$
This is not the same as $Pr(\textrm{one H and one T in any order})$.
Infact, to find $Pr(\textrm{one H and one T in any order})$ you need
$Pr(HT)+Pr(TH)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$
The statement $Pr(Tails)=\frac{3}{4}$ makes no sense as it is written, either. If you mean at least one tail in two tosses then this is not independent to at least one head.
Update
This is based on a question in a comment.
The events $HT$ and $HT$ are not independent.
$Pr(HT)=\frac{1}{4}$, $Pr(TH)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{16}$.
However the events $HT$ and $TH$ are mutually exclusive so $Pr(HT\cap TH)=0\neq\frac{1}{16}$
Which means the events are not independent.

Thank you for your answer. I guess I was wanting to check if P(TH or HT) was independent. I cant seem to find a mathematical way to check it. I know that both P(TH) and P(HT) are independent separately. I used ChatGPT and they say its independent(but I know they are wrong lots of times), but you say it dependent. The only way I can see that its dependent is that we have to know what the first toss is so that we can get the correct next value for us to get a HT or TH. Could you elaborate a bit on this please

Ah, ok. I will update my answer.

Thanks for your reply, but I wanted to find if P(TH or HT) is independent and not P(TH and HT)

HT or TH is just one event. Independence requires two events. What is the second event? For example, you can ask if HT and (HT or TH) are independent but just asking is (HT or TH) independent is a meaningless question.

Ok, thanks. I think I get it now.

Excellent. It can be confusing with the language at times.
